# How to make database able to read & write "ÆØÅ"?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So the problem is that i'm trying to upload a "new ico", my site is all about cryptocurrency. Everything is working as it did locally on my computer, but when im trying to upload a new ico it says this:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�rdi, whitepaper, social, avatar) VALUES ('KickCoin','Random','Random','Random'' at line 1"

�rid = Should be saying "Værdi".

I read that the problem defiantly is something connection based with the database or so (because i didn't have the problem local)? But how do i fix it, so that my website will show "ÆØÅ" and how do i make the database able to understand "ÆØÅ", so that i can upload?

Thanks in advance, 
Victor

Comment: Make sure the files are saved as UTF-8 encoding and upload them to the server in binary mode, but ascii should work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the database collation to

> latin1_swedish_ci/utf8mb4_bin

This will work. Its working fine for my sites.

Comment: How do i change the Database Collation, im using phpmyadmin. thanks in advance :)